# eclipse luna format printing

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded eclipse Luna. But the format printing is not working. let consider the simple code given below:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a=4;
        System.out.printf("%d",a);
    }
}
```

It is showing error message below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>     The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

What may be the possible cause and solution?

Comment: You need to post the complete code.

Comment: First thing to do is *not run the code until it compiles*. It should have given you a warning when you tried to run it - at that point, stop, and look at the problem list.

Comment: If you type `java -version` into the command line (or your equivalent), what do you get? Also, in `Eclipse`, go to `Help->About Eclipse` and post what you have next to the "Version" block.

Comment: actually the same code is compiling and running in windows cmd and neat beans. i am using win 8 64 bit.@ Jon Skeet

Comment: Your language level / compiler level / compliance level is wrong (very likely currently set on `1.4`). Set it to at least `1.5` (this Java version introduced the autoboxing feature): http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/ref-preferences-compiler.htm

Comment: @Mike Elofson..i found the following    "java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)" and for eclipse "Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)"

Comment: Compiler compliance level is 1.8, shall i need to change? @Tom

Comment: @BlackSwan Well, if it was on `1.8` you wouldn't get this error ... strange

Comment: Maybe project specific compiler settings are enabled? Open the properties of your Java project, select "Java Compiler" and check if "Enable project specific settings" is enabled and if the selected JDK differs from the Eclipse JDK settings.

Comment: i think i should tell the story behind, encountered same problem past when reinstall windows, but somehow on that time i solved that, the version was Kepler. but this time after reinstalling windows, i used the same Kepler(that was working) and found this problem. then thought a newer version may solve it and take Luna, also found in eclipse Luna.@tom

Comment: yes...it has solved my problem for this particular project. though my problem solved, but i am not completely satisfied cause i don't understand it clearly. would u please tell the reasons and suggest me how i will avoid this problem in future for other projects @Katja Christiansen

Comment: Unfortunately, the only tip I can give you is to keep in mind that the compiler compliance level can be set global or local for Eclipse projects. You can see a list of all projects with local compiler level settings by clicking the "Configure Project Specific Settings..." links in the general Java -> Compiler preferences.

Comment: There r also some projects,having same problem, but after correcting one, rest of them were corrected..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have got my answer from the comment of @Katja Christiansen. the comment has given below, as @Katja Christiansen not write the solution in asnswer for that i am wrriting it here let other can find that the problem has solved..

"Maybe project specific compiler settings are enabled? Open the properties of your Java project, select "Java Compiler" and check if "Enable project specific settings" is enabled and if the selected JDK differs from the Eclipse JDK settings. –  Katja Christiansen "

after trying it, the printf has solved and it solved for all the existing project.

Thanks @Katja Christiansen for ur cooperation.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Compiler compliance level` might not be correct.

You can find it in Eclipse here:
Project > Properties > Java Compiler

Make sure it's set to 1.5 or higher.

Comment: @Tom I'm sorry, fixed it! I hope this is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `format` method:

```
int a = 4;
System.out.format("%d", a);
```

Comment: i tried and found ..."Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method format(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)"

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Tell me if you get any errors with this: `System.out.printf("%s", String.valueOf(a));`

Comment: i am using "java version "1.8.0_25" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)" and the code fragment given same result. @Malik Brahimi

Comment: I have no idea what to tell you. Perhaps, you are overriding the function.

Comment: I recommend installing Java again.

Comment: The `printf` method was added in Java 1.5. Perhaps, it is a settings issue in your IDE.

Comment: actually that is a simple code, the code is stated above, that is all. Only one method, that is main. @

Comment: As I said, it is probably an IDE compatibility setting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Eclipse Luna` and the following `main` method runs for me:

```
public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 4;
        System.out.printf("%d", a);
    }

}
```

Gives me the output of:

`4`

Comment: This doesn't really address the OPs question of what could be wrong in his case.

Comment: do we really need exception here? cause i think all these are syntax and logically right.

Comment: I removed the exception, that was from a previous example that I made for another SO post. The exception is not required.